# What's the best way to store page links in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Is there any way to optimize the storage of links to different pages so that I don't have to write the same links on each page?

I am also interested in your practices on this issue. Do you copy links conditionally on every page or do you use some other methods?

I thought about storing them in an `.env` file, but that doesn't seem to work with client components. I also created a file with changes where there was an array with all the pages, but this is also a bad option, because through the code you can get links to private pages that are intended only for the administration.

Comment: You can simply create a constant object and store it somewhere, and whenever you need a link you can get it from there. - this is native JavaScript, no magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use enums for this purpose like:

```
export enum DashboardRoutes {
  Overview = '/dashboard',
  Profile = '/dashboard/profile',
  ProfileUploadResume = '/dashboard/profile/upload-resume',
  Feedback = '/dashboard/feedback',
  MarkedQuestions = '/dashboard/marked-questions'
}
```

Also I don't understand your concern about private pages.
You have some protected routes that have to perform an authorization check on the cookie, etc. So that shouldn't be a problem.

So in general, I store links in different enums like adminRoutes, userRoutes, etc and when the user is hitting them, an authorization check is applied and based on the permissions that the user has, I decide to show the page or not.